# How not to get NULL string or value from Database when fields are null using conditional statement?

Tags: c#

Need a little push here. Please.

I created a simple greeting that say hello to the user using the user first and last name:
However, I added an if statement so that if the database table has no names (the names are optional), then I only want to display a greeting but without the name:

So if user has name in db, greeting will be: Good morning Penda Bear: and simply good evening if the names are null.

However I still get Null in the greeting. I could filter this at the stored procedure but I need the data even when there are no names.

Note: The *Method LoadProfile* simplys loads the DataSet.

***Code Rough draft:***

```
public static string CreateGreeting()
{
string userFirstName = LoadProfile().Tables[0].Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString();
string userLastName = LoadProfile().Tables[0].Rows[0]["LastName"].ToString();

Int16 intHourOfDay = Convert.ToInt16(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH"));

if ((intHourOfDay < 12) & (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userLastName)))
{
return "Good Morning " + userFirstName + " " + userLastName;
}
else
{
return "Good Morning";
}
}
```

This is what the result looks like: *Good Morning NULLL nNULL*.

New to C# and confused as to why I get null even when using *IsNullOrEmpty*.
I know because it is simply a string value but how do I get rid of it?

Comment: @Tim, `&&` instead of `&` doesn't change the semantics of that snippet at all.

Comment: It's not a bitwise operator with bools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting the `NULL` string (literal string) on `userLastName` or `userFirstName` you might be storing it wrong in the database. If `LoadProfile().Tables[0].Rows[0]["FirstName"]` is `DBNull`, then `ToString()` should return an empty string (`String.Empty`) and not the literal `NULL` string.

As per [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkbzs85t.aspx) for `DBNull.ToString`:

> Returns an empty string (String.Empty).

## Invalid

***(This doesn't really apply (see Joey's comment below))***

As for your second question:

> New to C# and confused as to why I get null even when using IsNullOrEmpty. I know because it is simply a string value but how do I get rid of it?

Your `and` operator doesn't do what you want. You are doing a `bitwise and` in the if. You want a `comparison/logical and` which is `&&` in c#:

```
if ((intHourOfDay < 12) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userLastName)))
```

Comment: Well, it's wrong in the sense that it doesn't do what he wants to do. The operator itself is not wrong, of course :-) . I've reworded the sentence.

Comment: Quoting from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sbf85k1c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx): »For **bool** operands, `&` computes the logical AND of its operands; that is, the result is **true** if and only if both its operands are **true**.« – Nothing bitwise there at all.

Comment: You are indeed right, actually... coming from C/C++ where booleans were actually ints, I hadn't seen this difference for C#. I've marked that part from my answer as not valid.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I was very confused by the BitWise stuff as I have read many books indicating what I did is in fact correct. && Short Circuit & evaluates both statement?? And also, I checked the DB and I did enter a value wrong when I manually entered null to test. But my insert method is set to enter DBNull.Value if an input is wrong. So the solution or explanation will be to first check if the value is DBNull than set to empty??

Comment: The problem here was that the value you were getting from the database was not `DBNull`, you were getting a literal string containing the word `NULL`, so there was actually a first and last name (someone called "null null") so the outcome of the program was right. If you get a null value, and not a string containing the word `NULL`, then the outcome should be correct.

Comment: JCL and Joey thanks for your time and effort, I really appreciate you taking your time to explain. Not sure why the down vote but I am not going to be bothered by that.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy you tend get plenty of downvotes with no explanation on StackOverflow... I myself have a decent share of them. Don't worry about it :-)

Comment: Some people will take the time and energy to down-vote something rather than adding anything constructive. Thanks JCL. See you around.

Answer (score 2):

```
var row =LoadProfile().Tables[0].Rows[0];

string? firstName = row.Field<string?>( "FirstName" );
string? lastName= row.Field<string?>( "LastName" );

if ((System.DateTime.Now.Hour < 12) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName)))
{
     return "Good Morning " + firstName + " " + lastName;
}
else
{
      return "Good Morning";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [string.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) extension method as part of a [ternary statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
return "Good morning" + string.IsNullOrEmpty(userFirstName) 
                        ? "!" 
                        : userFirstName + string.IsNullOrEmpty(userLastName) 
                                          ? string.Empty 
                                          : userLastName;
```

Or a slightly more advanced method which flattens out your conditional logic:

```
return string.Format("Good {0}{1}{2} {3}"
                     , intHourOfDay < 12 ? "morning" : "evening"
                     , string.IsNullOrEmpty(userFirstName) ? "!" : " "
                     , userFirstName
                     , userLastName
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Test your values against the constant `System.DBNull.Value`.  If the values are equal to `System.DBNull.Value`, then set the values of your variables to string.empty.

Also, you have an error in that you're using a bit-wise and (`&`) instead of a logical and (`&&`).

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are using, even when you solve your trouble by checking against `DBNull.Value`, will not work in a real world application. You should consider using some OR/M Micro ORM libary to avoid that repetitive ADO.NET plumbing, that will always lead to some bug.

Comment: The sound of OR/M Micro ORM libary makes want to grab a drink: :)